# PHP Code to display article title in Joomla Featured Blog View Menu Item

Tags: php, joomla1.7

I am currently developing a Joomla 1.7 website, And I am using J2Store shopping Cart so I have to make make an article for every Product.

Then to display I create a Joomla Featured Articles Menu Item for the appropriate Category, my problem is this, The default Article Title isn't really appropriate for the page layout and because there will be many products / articles so as a time saver I would like to include some PHP code to retrieve the Article Title I have tried the following used in conjunction with the Sourcerer plugin.

```
<?php echo JFactory::getDocument()->getTitle(); ?>
```

But unfortunately it displays the Menu Title not the individual Article Titles, I also found the following code but I cant get it to work with Joomla 1.7

```
<?php   
    $option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
$view = JRequest::getCmd('view');
if ($option=="com_content" && $view=="article") {
    $ids = explode(':',JRequest::getString('id'));
    $article_id = $ids[0];
    $article =& JTable::getInstance("content");
    $article->load($article_id);
    echo $article->get("title");
} ?>
```

Comment: Hi Shaz thx for your response, I am not sure about what you mean by output, but the only thing that is being outputted  on page after inserting code is <p>&nbsp;</p> I also tried changing $view=="article" to $view=="blog" & $view=="featured" but same result, the truth is I am a total newb with php so I am not sure if I am missing some code, anyway thx again.

Comment: What do you see if you type `echo $option;` and `echo $view;` after the third line of the code you pasted here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$product =& JTable::getInstance("content");
$product->load($product_id);
echo $product->get("title");
```

And replace `$product_id` with whatever ID needed.

Comment: Thx for your suggestion Jamie but I need to get the Article ID Dynamically, Will have hundreds of articles.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this file:

> components/com_content/views/featured/tmpl/default.php

That's the original template for the Featured Articles view, you can override it as explained in this link:

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

to include a piece of code like this (in the file you created on your template folder):

```
<?php 
foreach($this->items as $fItem): 
    echo $fItem->title.'<br/>';
endforeach;
?>
```

Voilà, you will see all the titles from the displayed featured articles.

Comment: Thx Shaz, if I understand correctly i put the code I create in my Templates HTML / com_content / featured / default_item.php, not directly in the article.

Comment: As you can see, the file is default.php